# Why are my variables not working, returning "<built-in method"?

Tags: python

I am new to Python and have run into this issue multiple times while coding projects. Whenever I try to change a variable that is provided by the user, the terminal displays this message: <built-in method upper of str object at 0x102760528>.

This seems to happen when I am taking input from a user and altering it. For example, in my current program, I am taking a letter and string from the user and determining if the letter they provided is also in the string. (Capitalization included)

[Current state of troubleshooting code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeBmk.png)

```
def check_letter():
    count = 0

    User_letter = str(input("Enter a single letter: "))
    User_String = str(input("Now, enter a string: "))

    Cap_inp = User_letter.upper
    Low_inp = User_letter.lower
    print(Cap_inp)
    print(Low_inp)

    for letter in User_String:
        if letter ==  Cap_inp or letter == Low_inp:
            count+=1
        print(count)
    if count > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    
print(check_letter())
```

I have tried using User_input.upper and User_input.lower instead of setting up the variables. This just had the same issue.

I expect the program to capitalize and lowercase the letter provided by the user
(a -> A or A ->) to then check against the string. If the letter matches, it will increase the count and return True.

How would I fix the program so that I can use these variables?

Comment: call the functions, `.upper()` and `.lower()` [Check the functions here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=lower#str.lower)

Comment: Additionally: There is no need to call `str` for the return value of `input`, as `input` already returns a string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def check_letter():
    count = 0

    User_letter = str(input("Enter a single letter: "))
    User_String = str(input("Now, enter a string: "))

    Cap_inp = User_letter.upper()
    Low_inp = User_letter.lower()

    for letter in User_String:
        if letter == Cap_inp or letter == Low_inp:
            count += 1

    if count > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    print(check_letter())
```

Comment: Thank you for putting in the full code change. I forgot that I needed to include the parenthesis. I'm not familiar with python syntax, so I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

change as following:

instead of

```
Cap_inp = User_letter.upper
Low_inp = User_letter.lower
```

use

```
Cap_inp = User_letter.upper()
Low_inp = User_letter.lower()
```

Comment: I appreciate the correction, I spent way too long trying to figure this out LOL. Thank you